# Spring Autowire retrieves the wrong class

Tags: java, spring-boot, autowired

I have

```
public abstract class AbstractClass<T> {
  public abstract MyStatus getStatus();
  public void test() {
     System.out.println(getStatus().testField());
  }
}
```

for Dogs I have

```
@Component("dogs")
public class Dogs extends AbstractClass<Dogs>{
   @Autowired
   MyStatus statusField;

   @PostConstruct
   private void init() {
      statusField.setTest("dogs");
   }

   public getStatus() {
     return statusField;
   }
}
```

for cats I have

```
@Component("cats")
public class Cats extends AbstractClass<Cats>{
   @Autowired
   MyStatus statusField;

   @PostConstruct
   private void init() {
      statusField.setTest("cats");
   }

   public getStatus() {
     return statusField;
   }
}
```

and for the StatusContainer I have

```
@Component
@Data
public class MyStatus<T> {
   public String test; // and other options from the application.properties file
}
```

I would expect that if I `@Autowired` `Dogs` I get for the status field `dogs` and for the `Cats` I'll get `cats`.

```
public class ClassA {
   @Autowired
   @Qualifier("dogs")
   Dogs myDogEntity;
}

public class ClassB {
   @Autowired
   @Qualifier("cats")
   Cats myCatEntity;
}
```

Matter of fact is that if I print the information of `MyStatus` I get everytime `cats` (or everytime `dogs`). I would have exptected that the container is initiated differently and injected with the appropriate instance. But thats not true.

Is there a *simple* way to have separete containers for different objects instead of injecting the same?

**UPDATE** Unfortunately I have had some typos in my orginal code. Fixed them - hopefully all.

I finally figured out that the major problem is/was that Spring creates only one instance of a component. In my case `MyStatus`. Consequently this one instance is injected into the other classes. Any manipulation on this one class will lead to the side effect that it manipulates the other.

My solution: Split the config into two parts - one which is Spring related and one the instance, e.g. `Cats` or `Dogs` will handle indiviudally - without Spring (injection)!!!

Comment: because `typo` is my friend :-/  Corrected the post

Comment: you mean `@Qualifier("dogs")` and `@Qualifier("cats")`, right?

Comment: Yeah right - just another `typo` :-( ... see the other comment

Comment: That is correct Leo, as by default the scope is Singleton, only one instance of each component is created. Another way it would be inside Dogs and cats, you dont inject the MyStatus, instead you create the unstance by hand so you end up with different instances. MyStatus looks like a Model, not a Component.

Comment: Hi @Brother ;-) since I need in `MyStatus` as well properties from Spring I finally ended up in a split (like mentioned above). You mentioned `Model` is there anything which Spring provides? I didn't find much after looking around. Just more for my curiosity.

Comment: Hi @LeO, I just posted an answer of how to achieve this without breaking into 2 classes.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your problem is that by default, the scope is Singleton on Spring and you end up having the same instance of MyStatus in both Dogs and Cats.

There is a simple way of achieving this, for the class MyStatus, you can set the scope to Prototype:

```
@Data
@Component
@Scope(value = ConfigurableBeanFactory.SCOPE_PROTOTYPE)
public class MyStatus<T> {
   public String test; 
}
```

This way, you don't need to change anything else. Because Spring will create a new instance for everybody that requests to inject it.

This way, the classes Cats and Dogs will have different instances of MyStatus.

Comment: Also, I let as public Sting test; because your example was like this, but because you have lombok, it should be private. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

You have to update your code and correct the Typing mistakes, I've posted below with correction.

```
public class ClassA {
   @Autowired
   @Qualifier("dogs")
   Dogs myDogEntity;
}

public class ClassB {
   @Autowired
   @Qualifier("cats")
   Cats myCatEntity;
}
```

Comment: Well that was just a `typo` - unfortunately. It didn't solve my problem.

Comment: I can see now edited post. If the problem is resolved then it should be in the answer part not in the question section as `My solution` so other's also can find the solution in a proper manner.